# Sprintf & Scanf

Tags: c, printf, scanf

I've been trying to figure out sprintf and scanf using the examples in this article:  https://www.udemy.com/blog/sprintf-c/#respond

```
// example 1
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
   char *stringa = “We Are Dismantling a String”;
   char *one, *two, *three, *four, *five;
   sscanf(stringa, “%s %s %s %s %s”, one, two, three, four, five);

   return(0);
}
```

and

```
//  Example 2
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
   char *stringa[30];
   int *fingers = 5;  
   sprintf(stringa, "Number of fingers making up a hand are %f", fingers); 
   puts(stringa);

   return(0);
}
```

I can't get the variable to initialize in example 1 and example 2 comes back with a whole list of errors.  I could use some help figuring out why these lines of code don't work.

Comment: Are you sure about the double quotes you're using in the code you have posted? Those are not the usual double-quotes `"` that the compiler would expect.

Comment: Do you really use `“` and `”` instead of `"` in your source code? Tbh I cannot even type those kinds of quotes, they aren't on my keyboard.

Comment: Are you programming in word or such? Because smart-quotes are seldom appropriate while programming, and certainly not where you used them.

Comment: Oh I see, it's copy pasted from `udemy.com`. Speaks a lot about the website's quality.

Comment: The first is UB: None of `one` to `five` was initalized. Style-tip: `return` is not a function call, leave out the superfluous parentheses.

Comment: `sprintf(stringa, "Number of fingers making up a hand are %f", fingers);`?? `fingers` is an `int`-pointer (initialized to 0x5) and read as a `double`. Stop using code from this website.

Comment: I use " maybe its just a cut paste issue?  I am using gedit to write my code.

Comment: No, it's your source website. Pick up some other tutorial or whatever. The code on this site is nonsense.

Comment: Yeah, I thought about just leaving it.  But, I'm new to coding and I want to know why it doesn't work so I can learn what not to do :)

Comment: I recommend reading the [C tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/c/info), and following some of the links there too...

Comment: The page you are "learning" from is utterly terrible, the text contains dozens of errors and the code is completely wrong. Blacklist that page immediately! (and possibly the entire site, as they clearly have no quality control)

Comment: That bad huh. No wonder its been such a pain trying to get it to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To complete [Jaochim Pileborg's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24972179/841108), you should use arrays, not pointers, so code your first `main` as

```
int main() {
  char *stringa = "We Are Dismantling a String";
  char onew[16], twow[16], threew[16], fourw[16], fivew[16];
  if (sscanf (stringa, 
              "%15s %15s %15s %15s %15s", 
              onew, twow, threew, fourw, fivew) < 5)
    fprintf (stderr, "something got wrong\n");
  return 0;
}
```

<sup>As [Chux](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2410359/chux) commented, you want a `%15s` for a `char onew[16];` because a 16 byte buffer can contain 15 non-space chars plus the required terminating null byte. BTW, I would in fact either explicitly initialize every buffer with e.g. `char onew[16]={0};` or preferably clear each of them using `memset (onew, 0, sizeof(onew));` *before* the call to `sscanf`. I hate uninitialized local buffer strings.</sup>

The `main` of the second example should not compile without warnings (if using `gcc -Wall -g`)  and you should *never* use `sprintf` but [snprintf(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/snprintf.3.html) (or possibly [asprintf(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/asprintf.3.html) when available).

```
int main() {
 char stringa[30];
 int fingers = 5;  
 snprintf(stringa, sizeof(stringa), 
          "Number of fingers making up a hand are %d", fingers); 
 puts(stringa);
 return(0); }
```

Notice that I changed the type of `stringa`, `fingers` and used `%d` ...

You should blacklist the site telling you such crap.

BTW, take the good habit of enabling all warnings & debug info in your compiler. With [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) compile with `gcc -std=c99 -Wall -g`. Learn to **use the debugger** (`gdb`) and to improve your code till you get no errors and no warnings.

Comment: Thanks. I'm getting old. Should put my near-vision glasses :-(

Comment: Curious, why use `"%16s %16s %16s %16s %16s"` instead of `"%16s%16s%16s%16s%16s"`: readability?.  Further, confident it should be `"%15s%15s%15s%15s%15s"` as 15 is the max number of char to scan.

Answer (score 4):

Rgarding your first program, the pointers are just pointers, and as they are uninitialized their value (i.e. where they point to) is indeterminate. Using them, especially as a destination to write to, leads to [*undefined behavior*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

To solve this you either need to allocate memory and assign to the pointers, or use array of sufficient length.

---

Regarding your second program, `fingers` is a pointer, and you tell the compiler to point it at *address* `5`, not to the *Value* `5`.

You then tell `printf` to print a floating point value, and give it the pointer as argument. This will once again lead to undefined behavior as `printf` will treat the pointer as a `double` value and not a pointer.

To solve this problem don't declare `fingers` as a pointer, and use the correct `printf` format `"%d"` (for signed decimal integer).

---

I also recommend you read some references for the function, like the following:

- http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf
- http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf

Comment: Thanks.  I've been reading tons of stuff on it but these examples seemed so simple and easy to digest.